# How to conveniently send PDF to Kindle DX?

Tags: data-transfer, kindle-dx

I have Kindle DX and Kindle Paperwhite.  The SendToKindle app can only send PDF from Mac computers to Kindle Paper White but not Kindle DX?  Any better way to do it than having to connect physical USB cables every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Amazon documentation](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200375640), you should have a Send-to-Kindle email address:

> When you register your Kindle DX, you'll automatically be assigned a Send-to-Kindle e-mail address. You can find this address from your Kindle's Settings screen:

1. From the Home screen, select Menu. Select Settings, then use the
   Next Page button to scroll to the second page.
2. Your Kindle device [name]@kindle.com e-mail address is listed under the Device E-mail heading.
3. Learn more about modifying your Send-to-Kindle E-mail address on [Manage Your Content and Devices](http://amazon.com/myk).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is transferring data this way free?

Comment: It's free unless you use Amazon's Whispernet service, which transmits over 3g, and requires a confirmation that you're willing to pay the price per megabyte to transfer over 3g. So yes, it's free :).